# Why doesn't Subplot using Pandas show x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

When I plot single plots with panda dataframes I have an x-axis.
However, when I make a subplot and try to make a shared x-axis the way I would when using numpy arrays without pandas, there are no numbers labels
I only want the numbers and label to appear on the last plot as they share the same x-axis.

The data loaded and the plot produced can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hTmTSkIcYl-usv_CCxLl8U6bAoO6tMRh

This is for combining and plotting the data logged from two different logging devices which represent the same time period.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1=pd.read_csv('data1.csv', sep=',',header=0)
df1.columns.values
cols1 = list(df1.columns.values)

df2=pd.read_csv('data2.dat', sep='\t',header=18)
df2.columns.values
cols2 = list(df2.columns.values)

start =10000
stop = 30000


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True, figsize=(10, 10))


df1.iloc[start:stop].plot(x=cols1[0], y=cols1[1], ax=axes[0])
df1.iloc[start:stop].plot(x=cols1[0], y=cols1[2], ax=axes[0])
df1.iloc[start:stop].plot(x=cols1[0], y=cols1[3], ax=axes[2])
df1.iloc[start:stop].plot(x=cols1[0], y=cols1[4], ax=axes[2])
df2.iloc[start:stop].plot(x=cols2[0], y=cols2[3], ax=axes[3])
ax3.set_xlabel("Time [s]")  

plt.show()
```

I expect there to be numbers and a label on the x-axis but instead, it only gives the pandas label "#timestamp"

UPDATE: I have found something that hints at the problem. I think the problem is due to the two files not having identical time spacing, the first column of each file is time, they are roughly 1 sample per second but not exactly. If I remove the x=cols[x] parts it then shows numbers on the x-axis but then there is a shift in time between the two plots as they are not plotting against time but rather against the index in the dataframe. 
I am currently trying to interpolate the data so that they have the same x-axis but I would not have expected that to be necessary.

Comment: You forgot to write the for loop it seems

Comment: What are you expecting `ax.set_xticklabels([])` to do? This will remove any tick labels on your last subplot. Also, you need `ax.set_xlabel` (not `ax.xlabel`) to change the label.

Comment: @Sheldore I originally had a loop but it actually made it messy when I wanted to change things like colours and position of the individual plots, I have now removed the x variable as it was not relevant to the problem

Comment: @busybear Yes you are right, ax.set_xticklabels([]) is not what I needed, I was trying different things to try make the axis appear. While ax.set_xlabel  has the right description, adding it doesn't change anything.  I actually thought the axis would be there by default and I wouldn't need to call it.